# bitcoind: How to generate new address and broadcast?

Tags: bitcoind

I have my own server running bitcoind. Could you tell me how to generate new bitcoin address, sign and broadcast? My goal is that I can see the generated address's balance on Blockchain.info. As for you, my question may be very easy but I am looking for the way for a long time...

bitcoind's version is 0.9.2.

```
$ bitcoind getinfo
{
    "version" : 90200,
    "protocolversion" : 70002,
    "walletversion" : 60000,
    "balance" : 0.00000000,
    "blocks" : 335538,
    "timeoffset" : -1,
    "connections" : 21,
    "proxy" : "",
    "difficulty" : 39457671307.13873291,
    "testnet" : false,
    "keypoololdest" : 1418654127,
    "keypoolsize" : 101,
    "paytxfee" : 0.00000000,
    "relayfee" : 0.00001000,
    "errors" : ""
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have any bitcoins, so you can't create, sign, and broadcast a transaction.

As for generating a new address, use the `getnewaddress` RPC.  It will give you an address you can give someone else to send you bitcoins.  Once you have bitcoins, you can create and broadcast a transaction in one step using either the `sendtoaddress` RPC or the `sendmany` RPC.

Use `help getnewaddress`, `help sendtoaddress`, and `help sendmany` to learn more about each RPC.

Comment: Thank you. I run "bitcoind getnewaddress" and I can see the address on blockchain.info. I thought that I had to broadcast the transaction of created new address.. but it seems not be necessary. Now I'm checking out "sendtoaddress"

Comment: I could send btc by using "sendtoaddress". The command seems to include sign and broadcast. Thanks